# Android Studio's manifest merger not working correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2, and having manifest merge error and the following is the error message

> Merging Errors:
>
> Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 11 declared in library /path/to/my/project/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/24.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.graphics.drawable.animated" to force usage

Android Studio doesn't allow me to run(CTRL + R) my application because there is no default activity. But the default activity is declared in a product flavor's manifest.

When I run `./gradlew app:dependencies`, the only occurrence of `animated-vector-drawable` was here;

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.1.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1
```

I think this should be ok because the min sdk version of `appcompat-v7` is 7.

A build command `./gradlew app:assembleFlavor1Debug` just works fine. It successfully builds apk file, and when I open it from APK Analyzer in Android Studio and see AndroidManifest.xml, everything is merged as expected.

The most weird thing is, Android Studio doesn't complain anything about min sdk mismatch **if I change the name of the project directory shorter** like `project` to `prj`

After that, everything just works fine. Merged manifest view doesn't have any error and I can run the application from Android Studio pressing CTRL+R.
But when I revert the directory name, it comes again.

Of course I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project several times, also tried `Invalidate Caches / Restart`, `git checkout -f`, `git clean -xdf`, `rm -rf project/` and `git clone` again, and everything.

I just wonder if the length of the name of project directory really matters.

Comment: @sasikumar please read the question thoroughly.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.bg/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html vector drawables are supported on 7+, animated vector drawables on 11+ . And it seems you set minSdk as 9 somewhere in your project

Comment: @X3Btel sure I set my app's minsdk to 9. And it doesn't make sense to me that I have to set minsdk to 11+ to use appcompat-v7. And as I explained in the questions, changing directory name gets rid of the error. Is this normal? Is there any naming rule for a project directory?

Comment: In the link i showed you explicitly said that AnimatedVectorDrawable wants min 11. The name changing most likely just breakes the lint check. those kind of errors does not break the build, you can always ignore them- but your app will crash in devices 9-11 when you try to use AnimatedVectorDrawable

Comment: It seems that assuming v7 library ports all its functionality to sdk7 is wrong- Different part of it still depend on different SDK versions

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I concluded that the min sdk version of `appcompat-v7` is actually not 7 from version 24.

I haven't used any features of vector animation, but the error occurred when the support library version is changed from 23 to 24.

There might be some codes or resources in the library that requires `animated-vector-drawable`. Now I think I have to rollback the version to 23.

And I also found that `appcompat-v7:25` itself requires the min sdk **9+**. I know this is weird but this can be found from AndroidManifest.xml in .aar file under a support library repository, and when I created an empty project with min sdk 7 for testing, I got a build error that was saying that the min sdk should be higher than or equal to 9.

(Then why does its name have `v7` in it?)

Thanks @X3Btel, your comment helped too.